# How to practice jumping over cars with disc brakes and SPD shoes?

Tags: safety, disc-brake, technique, spd

This question [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/most-favoriable-collision-with-a-car-how-should-i-act-before-collision-supposin/4323#4323) raises a sub-question, to avoid accidents. I am looking for some safe ways to practice jumping over cars. I use SPD shoes and disc brakes because I have noticed that I can burst very fast with them. I have no idea whether it is possible to jump over cars easily without SPD shoes and disc brakes. So any good ideas for safe practising?

Comment: Very very carefully, wearing as much protective gear (helmet, knee/elbow pads, etc) as you can. :)

Comment: Do you mean jumping onto cars to avoid being hit, like the moz's answer indicates, or jumping as in BMX-style jumping?

Comment: @Neil Fein: to avoid being hit (although BMX-style jumping may be good idea, not sure yet what it really means).

Comment: BMX is a different sort of biking, like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXSago8ijMo&feature=related). (Just asking for tagging purpposes.)

Comment: What if the car you want to leap is equipped with drum brakes and look shoes, instead of disk brakes and SPD shoes?
#humour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More useful for you would be going along to a basic aikido course, or if that's not available judo, gymnastics, ninjitsu or some other form that teaches you how to roll. Forget the holds and throws and just learn how to roll. When you can confidently run full speed at a waist-high obstacle and dive-roll over it, you'll be in a better position to survive a bicycle-enhanced version of that.

Find a grassy children's playground with a suitable step, bank or ditch, and practice going over the handlebars. As freheit suggested in comments, wear protective equipment. I suggest starting slowly and using an old BMX rather than a bike you care about. The bmx will be easier to get off as well as cheaper.

To be honest this isn't something I would practice. What I get people to do when I'm training them is just turning the bike to one side and fall away from it. At walking speed. The idea is just to convince them that they're not going to die if they fall off, and to give them a few tips on keeping their arms bent. Mostly I use it to sell them on the idea of cycling gloves (and not riding in crappy footwear). Note that I've only done this where helmets are mandatory, but otherwise I'd also be selling people on helmets.

Comment: Why gloves? The roll they taught me is over the outside of one hand, then the shoulder, then the ribs on the opposite side of the body, buttocks, feet. They made us hold things while rolling to explicitly not use our hands.